# transform array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im new in JS and I hope you help me) I need to transform array of objects in this way:

```
const arr = [
  {id: 'key1', value: 1 },
  {id: 'key2', value: [1,2,3,4]}
 ...
]
const transformedArr = [
   {key1: 1},
   {key2: 1},
   {key2: 2},
   {key2: 3},
   {key2: 4},
   ....
 ]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ES6 spread syntax `...` with `map()` method.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 'key1', value: 1 },
  {id: 'key2', value: [1,2,3,4]}
]

var result = [].concat(...arr.map(({id, value}) => {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(e => ({[id]: e})) : {[id]: value}
}))

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `reduce()` instead of `map()` method.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 'key1', value: 1 },
  {id: 'key2', value: [1,2,3,4]}
]

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, {id, value}) {
  r = r.concat(Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(e => ({[id]: e})) : {[id]: value})
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are new to JS ..

Good Old JS with for loops might be easy for you to understand

```
const arr = [
  {id: 'key1', value: 1 },
  {id: 'key2', value: [1,2,3,4]}
]

const transformedArr  =[]


for(var i = 0 ; i < (arr.length); i++){

   var valArr = arr[i].value

   if( Array.isArray(valArr) ){ // to check if the value part is an array

      for(var j=0 ; j < valArr.length ; j++){

        transformedArr.push({id: arr[i].id,value:valArr[j] })

      }

   }else{

     transformedArr.push({id: arr[i].id,value:valArr })

   }

}

console.log(transformedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal features [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), because it add items without array and arrays to an array.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 'key1', value: 1 }, { id: 'key2', value: [1, 2, 3, 4] }],
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, a) => r.concat(
            [].concat(a.value).map(
                v => ({ [a.id]: v })
            )
        ),
        []
    );
      
console.log(result);
```